# Переместить первый и последний элемент в центр

Tags: python

Всем привет, изучаю слайсы и возник вопрос при решении одной задачи

Есть строка,

```
str = '11 22 333 44'
```

надо чтобы первый и последний элемент переместились в центр.
В результате должно получиться:

```
str = '22 11 44 333'
```

Подскажите)

Comment: Количество элементов всегда чётно? Если нет, то как определяется центр в случае нечётного количества элементов?

Comment: А зачем вам это требуется (Переместить первый и последний элемент в центр)?

Answer (score 1):

Если количество элементов всегда чётно, то так:

```
string = '11 22 333 44 555555 6'
lst = string.split()


mid = int(len(lst) / 2)

new_lst = lst[1:mid] + lst[:1] + lst[-1:] + lst[mid:-1]

new_str = ' '.join(new_lst)
```

Если количество элементов может быть нечётным, то укажите, что в этом случае понимать под "центром".

PS: И не используйте str для обозначения строки - иначе вы перезапишете одноимённую функцию.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [11, 124, 54, 674, 22, 86]
center = int(len(a)/2)
first = int(a[0])
last = int(a[-1])
a.insert(center, first)
a.insert(center + 1, last)
a.pop()
a.pop(0)
print(a)
#[124, 54, 11, 86, 674, 22]
```

Должно работать.